# evenly distribution / relaxation of 2D point sets inside domains

Tags: distribution, diagram, points, delaunay, voronoi

i am currently doing research for a project involving 2D Point Set modification as a sub-problem. The point sets itself will contain several clusters of points, which i will somehow need to separate from each other and then relax their points inside their clusters hull. Alternatively it is sufficient to get the hull-points of the clusters and use them as domains and distribute (roughly) evenly spaced points inside them. So the relaxation could be skipped.
I will need to process several point sets including ~100k vertices as a worst case scenario, so the algorithm used should be fast.
I know the complexity of this subject and thats why i do not want to reinvent the wheel but rather use existing code if possible. So far i found the following:

1. for point set relaxation: Fortunes/Sullivans "Sweep Line" algorithm: said to be the fastest single threaded voronoi diagram constructor. However the code seems to be very difficult to extend and the information extractable per default doesnt contain voronoi cell hull data (their vertex positions) wich at least would be needed compute the centroids and do a next relaxation iteration. In addition, any domains other than rectangular wouldnt be usable.
2. CVT: a bunch of versatile libraries for creating voronoi diagrams. It supports relaxation of points and also point sets inside user-specified regions.
3. CGAL: extensive framework with rudimentary MP support, but apparently no integrated relaxation method. I would need to create a delaunay triangulation of each of the point sets sub-cluster and feed this into a voronoi adaptor which then gives me iterators to query the voronoi cells hull data for further relaxation. It should support domains as far as i am through the docs (several thousand pages :)
4. some more, Voro++ for example which seems to work primarily in 3D; Triangle, which creates delaunay triangulations from given domains using area constraints so that one could use the triangles vertices as resulting points.

Ok, at the moment it seems to me that CVT should suit my needs while keeping this all quite simple. But I am not sure, so the question: has anybody experience with point set relaxation implementation, preferably using domains? What existing code would be preferable?

Thanks fur suggestions!t